# Firefox Linear Gradient in fancybox iframe causes transparency

Tags: css, firefox, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox popup (of type iframe) that contains textboxes with a background style of `background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafaf9 0%, #fafaf9 41%, #f5f5f4 100%);`, however when the fancybox is above any content, when the user types in a textbox there are spots where you can see through to the underlying content. I have noticed that in the generated styles in the firefox developer tools window (not firebug), it is setting a the background-color style to transparent, essentially making it so that when there is text entered in the textbox you can see through it where that text lies. I've tried other gradient syntax (to bottom, rgb, rgba, etc.), but they all give me this issue. Anyone have any idea what may be going on, or how to fix it?

Comment: if you are using iframe, you have to set the background property of your body tag individually in the page opened in fancybox

Comment: I have tried setting the background property of the body of the iframe to white but the issue persists. Firebug is showing my body tag's style attribute properly, but I can still see underlying elements from the main page until I type enough to fill the textbox, then it fixes itself and shows through to the white background that has been set. Regardless of which issue is being displayed, it still shouldn't happen. Is this a fancybox issue? Just a Firefox iframe issue?